# build error in x86 assembly code, " error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__srand referenced in function _main "

Tags: c, assembly, x86, build-error

> I am trying to build up an array reverser with the combination of x86 assembly code and C code. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 community and the attched image is the directory of my ArrayReverser project.
> [Directory of the ArrayReverser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxVdK.png)

> This is the code in Reverser.asm

```
.386
.model flat,c
.code

Reverser    proc
;function prolog
            ;push registers onto stack
            push ebp
            mov  ebp,esp
            push esi
            push edi

            xor eax,eax ;check if the user has passed a invalid array size
            mov edi,[ebp+8] ;first argument, the result after flipping the array
            mov esi,[ebp+12] ;second argument, the input from the user
            mov ecx,[ebp+16] ;third argument, the number of the array member
            test ecx,ecx

            lea esi,[esi+ecx*4-4] ;load the address of rhs instead of counting offset 
            pushfd ;stores the direction flag
            std ;set the flag to 1

@@:         lodsd
            mov [edi],eax
            add edi,4
            dec ecx
            jnz @B
            
            popfd
            mov eax,1

            ;pop registers off the stack
            pop edi
            pop esi
            pop ebp

            ret
Reverser    endp
end         Reverser
```

> And below is the code in ArrayReverser.cpp

```
// ArrayReverser.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" void Reverser(int* y, const int* x, int n);

int main()
 {
    const int n = 10;
    int x[n], y[n];

    srand(41);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            x[i] = rand() % 1000;
        }
    Reverser(y, x, n);

    printf("\n---------------------Array Revereser------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("i:     %5d       y: %5d        x: %5d\n", i, y[i], x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> And here are the error messages

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ArrayReverser, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Assembling Reverser.asm...
1>ArrayReverser.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__srand referenced in function _main
1>ArrayReverser.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__rand referenced in function _main
1>ArrayReverser.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func referenced in function _printf
1>ArrayReverser.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vfprintf referenced in function __vfprintf_l
1>MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport referenced in function __CRT_RTC_INIT
1>MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function __CRT_RTC_INITW
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strcpy_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strcat_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf_s referenced in function __vsprintf_s_l
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __wmakepath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __wsplitpath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wcscpy_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_GetModuleHandleW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_LoadLibraryExW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _terminate referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___current_exception referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___current_exception_context referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
1>C:\Users\Jack1109\source\repos\ArrayReverser\Debug\ArrayReverser.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "ArrayReverser.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

> I've solve the build error by removing the Reverser in the last line in Revereser.asm, like this.

```
.386
.model flat,c
.code

Reverser    proc
;function prolog
            ;push registers onto stack
            push ebp
            mov  ebp,esp
            push esi
            push edi

            xor eax,eax ;check if the user has passed a invalid array size
            mov edi,[ebp+8] ;first argument, the result after flipping the array
            mov esi,[ebp+12] ;second argument, the input from the user
            mov ecx,[ebp+16] ;third argument, the number of the array member
            test ecx,ecx

            lea esi,[esi+ecx*4-4] ;load the address of rhs instead of counting offset 
            pushfd ;stores the direction flag
            std ;set the flag to 1

@@:         lodsd
            mov [edi],eax
            add edi,4
            dec ecx
            jnz @B

            popfd
            mov eax,1

            ;pop registers off the stack
            pop edi
            pop esi
            pop ebp

            ret
Reverser    endp
            end
```

> I'm just really curious what causes the problem. Because in other x86 assembly code project, I've also included the asm file name in the last line. I guess it has something to do with the linking between Reverser.asm and ArrayReverser.cpp, but I want to know more about the details of the error.
> Thank you.

Comment: The symbol after the `end` sets the entry point for the program. Apparently if that is not `main` then the build does not link to the C runtime stuff. In any case you do not want your entry point to be `Reverser` so you have done the correct thing by removing it.

Comment: Also, you're mixing C and C++ in not so good ways, and are not including the right headers. For example, `printf` is undeclated in your program, because you're not including stdio.h. Which actually is a good idea, seeing this is C++ and not a C program.

Comment: @Jester do you mean if I leave it blank after the " end ", the program will continue with the rest of the C runtime stuff? But if I add " Reverser " after it, the program will stop at the assembly code and not proceed with the C runtime stuff? I'm not quite sure what you mean by saying setting the entry point for the program. And why is it showing " unresolved external symbol "? Which external symbol is it referring to?

Comment: No. When the operating system starts your program it has to know which address to transfer control to. That is the entry point. For C/C++ program this entry point is in the runtime library which does initialization and calls your `main`. If the entry point is set by you to something else then that will not happen. Also, and this is just a guess based on what you reported, in that case the build system will not link the runtime library at all. That library has all the functions that are reported as unresolved such as `srand`, `rand`,  etc.